# Database design of companies, products, accessories and associations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am trying to design a database for products manufactured by several companies, their accessories and the associations of both products and accessories with clients’ accounts.

How would you design such a database to achieve this functionality?

**BUSINESS RULES**

- A product is always associated to a company and a company can have many products.
- Apart from products, a company may also have accessories and, in some cases, combinations of these accessories (bundles).
- A company product can be associated with one or more accessories of the very same company or with a combination of these accessories (bundles).
- A client can associate to his account one product without accessories or the association of a product with one or several accessories or bundles (a combination of accessories).

**MY APPROACH**

Visit https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmxqzgagbw1sek1/Ejemplo.png?dl=0

To achieve that only existing combinations of products with accessories/bundles can be associated to a user restriction, I added the following business rule in the code: *If the combination exist in products_accessories, the combination is therefore eligible; otherwise the code will trigger an error*.

Finally, to make all possible combinations of products and accessories/bundles eligible, the table composed of products and accessories (products_accessories) has the following composite primary key: (id, product_id and accessory_id).

For example:

I have the p1 product and the following add-ons: a1, a2 and a3. a1 and a3 can be combined. In this example, the products_accessories table looks like this:

```
| id | product_id | accessory_id |
|----|------------|--------------|
| 1  | p1_id      | a1_id        |
| 2  | p1_id      | a2_id        |
| 3  | p1_id      | a3_id        |
| 4  | p1_id      | a1_id        |
| 4  | p1_id      | a3_id        |
```

Comment: a product may not belong to a company?

Comment: Nop, a product always belong to a company.

Comment: in this case I'd remove the relationship product-accessory

Comment: Ok, but if I remove the relationship how can I know the accessories that can be associated with a product? Not all accessories from a company can be associated with all company products.

Comment: each accessory already belongs to a company, so you can deal with accessories directly

Comment: Not all accessories from a company can be associated with all company products and a client can associate to his account one product without accessories or the association of a product with one or several accessories or bundles, but never a accessory without product.

Comment: so the user-accessory relationship is not intended to allow the client to associate with an accessory without a product, right?

Comment: Exactly. This business restriction are controlled in the code. Same that the other restriction, that only existing combinations of products with accessories/bundles can be associated to a user. First I check if user have a product associated and then if this accessory with product combination exist in products_accessories table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a 'bill of materials' type approach.

```
    +-------------+
    | COMPANIES   |
    +-------------+
    | #company_id |
    +-------------+
           |
  +--------^--------+   +-----------------+   +------------+
  | PRODUCTS        |---< CLIENT_PRODUCTS >---| CLIENTS    |
  +-----------------+   +-----------------+   +------------+
  | #product_id     |   | #client_id      |   | #client_id |
  | #company_id     |   | #product_id     |   +------------+
  |  is_offereable  |   | #company_id     |
  +-----------------+   +-----------------+
        |     |
+---------------------+
| PRODUCT_BUNDLES     |
+---------------------+
| #parent_product_id  |
| #child_product_id   |
| #company_id         |
|  quantity           |
+---------------------+
```

- COMPANIES

  - PK: company_id
- PRODUCTS

  - PK: product_id, company_id
  - FK: company_id REFERENCES COMPANIES company_id
- PRODUCT_BUNDLES

  - PK: parent_product_id, child_product_id, company_id
  - FK: parent_product_id, company_id REFERENCES PRODUCTS product_id, company_id
  - FK: child_product_id, company_id REFERENCES PRODUCTS product_id, company_id
- CLIENTS

  - PK: client_id
- CLIENT_PRODUCTS

  - PK: client_id, product_id, company_id
  - FK: client_id REFERENCES CLIENTS client_id
  - FK: product_id, company_id REFERENCES PRODUCTS product_id, company_id

The company_id is included as part of the PRODUCTS PK so that only products from the same company can of bundled.

The products tables initially includes the individual products and individual accessories. Individual products and accessories from the same company may be bundled together to form new 'products'. These new 'products' may in turn be bundled with indivudal products or accessories or other bundles to form more 'products'.

The is_offerable flag indicates whether the individual product, accessory or bundle may be associated with a client.

You may also be able to restrict which products are associated with a client by having a product type column on the PRODUCTS table and ensuring only products of type PRODUCT or bundles that include at least one PRODUCT are associated with clients.

Comment: Ok, but if a client can associate to his account only one product without accessories or the association of a product with one or several bundles the client_product table is not necessary?

Comment: The CLIENT_PRODUCTS table would be necessary as a client could offer several 'products' e.g. 'Product 1', 'Product 1 with Accessory A' and 'Product 1 With Accessories A and B' and one product could be offered by several clients. The CLIENT_PRODUCTS table would only not be necessary if all clients only offer one product or all products are only offered by one client, which does not appear to be the business rule.